# Width on a table

Tags: html, css

My line in turquoise color must be 5% width and I see it's a lot more? Why do I have this problem? Why the widths of each color are not respected?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <!-- CSS only -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <br><br>
      <div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="strikes.length > 0">
         <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th scope="col" style="width: 44%; text-align: center;">CALL</th>
                  <th class="exoPrice" scope="col" style="width: 12%;background-color: #dee2e657;">
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col" style="width: 44%; text-align: center">PUT</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <th scope="col" style="width: 3%; background-color: aqua;"></th>
                  <th scope="col" style="width: 25%; background-color: green;">Quantity</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have various width for the table cells, you need to have multiple tables.
Make sure that the width of all cells add up to 100%. So if you want to achieve a table row with a cell of 5% and another cell with 25% width, you need to have a third empty cell with 70%.
I have added background-color orange for the third cell in this case just for the visibility, but you can remove that.

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 44%; text-align: center;">CALL</td>
      <td class="exoPrice" scope="col" style="width: 12%; background-color: #dee2e657;"></td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 44%; text-align: center">PUT</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 5%; background-color: aqua;"></td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 25%; background-color: green;">Quantity</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 70%; background-color: orange;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```